# How to "flip" an equality proposition in Coq?

Tags: coq

If I'm in Coq and I find myself in a situation with a goal like so:

```
==================
  x = y -> y = x
```

Is there a tactic that can can take care of this in one swoop? As it is, I'm writing

```
intros H. rewrite -> H. reflexivity.
```

But it's a bit clunky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To "flip" an equality `H: x = y` you can use `symmetry in H`. If you want to flip the goal, simply use `symmetry`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a single tactic, then the [`easy`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Tactics.html) tactic handles this one immediately:

```
Coq < Parameter x y : nat.
x is assumed
y is assumed

Coq < Lemma sym : x = y -> y = x.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   x = y -> y = x

sym < easy.
No more subgoals.
```

If you take a look at the proof that the `easy` tactic found, the key part is an application of `eq_sym`:

```
sym < Show Proof.
(fun H : x = y => eq_sym H)
```

The heavier-weight `auto` tactic will also handle this goal in a single step.  For a *slightly* lower-level proof that produces exactly the same proof term, you can use the `symmetry` tactic (which also automatically does the necessary `intro` for you):

```
sym < Restart.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   x = y -> y = x

sym < symmetry.
1 subgoal

  H : x = y
  ============================
   x = y

sym < assumption.
No more subgoals.

sym < Show Proof.
(fun H : x = y => eq_sym H)
```